# java socket and Proxy authentication

Tags: java, proxy

I need a Java Socket client class that supports authenticated socks proxy, java.net.Proxy only supports one set of credentials for the whole JVM.  I have multiple proxies each with different logins.
here's what java's proxy Authenticator does, only one login for the whole JVM.  how do I have multiple?

```
Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator(){
  protected  PasswordAuthentication  getPasswordAuthentication(){
   PasswordAuthentication p=new PasswordAuthentication("xxx", "xxx".toCharArray());
   return p;
  }
 });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `Authenticator` implementation you can ask for the proxy the authentication is for using: `getRequestingHost()`.

Based on the value of `getRequestingHost()` you can return the `PasswordAuthentication` for that proxy.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41806422/java-web-start-unable-to-tunnel-through-proxy-since-java-8-update-111