# HTTP Proxy-Authentication with OpenCMIS client

Tags: proxy, opencmis, apache-chemistry

I am developing an OpenCMIS client using BindingType.Browser. Creating a session passing the required parameters for USER, PASSWORD, BROWSER_URL, BINDING_TYPE and REPOSITORY_ID works as expected. The session is created and further steps can be executed.

Now I want to make my client run on machines using HTTP proxies to access the internet. To specify the proxy to access I set the system properties http.proxyUrl and http.proxyPort. This works too as long as the proxy does not require authentication.

Well, that's the point where I am struggeling right now. I activated the authentication in my test proxy and in the client code I added the parameters PROXY_USER and PROXY_PASSWORD to create the session. But this doesn't seem to work. I already debugged the used StandardAuthenticationProvider to verify what happens. The HTTP-Header "Proxy-Authenticate" is created by the authentication provider but it seems that the chemistry framework is sending the request without that header. In the log of my proxy the received requests do not contain any security headers.

```
CONNECT my.server.org:443 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Java/1.8.0_111
Host: my.server.org
Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution in the following thread: [Java Web Start: Unable to tunnel through proxy since Java 8 Update 111](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41806422/java-web-start-unable-to-tunnel-through-proxy-since-java-8-update-111/43877148?noredirect=1#comment74806577_43877148).

Since Java 8 Update 111 the Basic authentication scheme has been deactivated, by default, in the Oracle Java Runtime, by adding "Basic" to the *jdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes* networking property when proxying HTTPS. For more information refer to [8u111 Update Release Notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u111-relnotes-3124969.html).

To re-activate the proxying you need to set *jdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""*. This cann be done via VM Argument when starting the application

```
-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""
```

or at runtime by setting the property in the main method of the application

```
System.setProperty("jdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes", "");
```