# proxy host name,port,username,password with httpurlconnection

Tags: java

```
private static void setProxy(String proxyHostName,int proxyport){
    proxy=new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP,new InetSocketAddress(proxyHostName,proxyport));
}

private static void setProxy(String proxyHostName,int proxyport,String username,String password){
    setProxy(proxyHostName,proxyport);
    if (username!=null && password!=null) {
        Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator() {

            public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return (new PasswordAuthentication(username, password.toCharArray()));
            }
        };
        Authenticator.setDefault(authenticator);
    }

}
```

this is code for proxy setting.I don't know why it's throwing this error.

exception:

java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns ""HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required""
    at sun.net.http://www.protocol.http.httpurlconnection.dotunneling%28httpurlconnection.java:2142/)
    at sun.net.http://www.protocol.https.abstractdelegatehttpsurlconnection.connect%28abstractdelegatehttpsurlconnection.java:183/)
    at sun.net.http://www.protocol.https.httpsurlconnectionimpl.connect%28httpsurlconnectionimpl.java:162/)
..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is incomplete and you did not specify which version of Java you are using, so I cannot say for certain, but I'm guessing this may be the reason:
[unable to tunnel through proxy since java-8-update-111](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41806422/java-web-start-unable-to-tunnel-through-proxy-since-java-8-update-111).

Try modifying your `setProxy()` method like this:

```
private static void setProxy(String proxyHostName, int proxyport, String username, String password){
    setProxy(proxyHostName,proxyport);
    if (username!=null && password!=null) {
        System.setProperty("jdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes", "");
        Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator() {
            public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return (new PasswordAuthentication(username, password.toCharArray()));
            }
        };
        Authenticator.setDefault(authenticator);
    }
}
```

Alternatively run your app with `-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=`.

More details on authenticated proxies in Java, can be found here: [authenticated http proxy with java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626549/authenticated-http-proxy-with-java).

There's also an explanation of this behavior here: [JDK-8210814](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8210814)

Comment: jdk version->1.8.0_91

Comment: Have you tried my solution? There's no guarantee that this restriction was added in Java 1.8.0_111. They may have simply not noticed before.

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41505219/unable-to-tunnel-through-proxy-proxy-returns-http-1-1-407-via-https)[Actual Problem].

Comment: Yes, I have tried your solution :@Konard Botor . It worked.Thankyou